# Confusion about memory layout when allocating memory with malloc

Tags: c, memory, malloc

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
struct data {
   char name[64];
};
struct fp {
   int (*fp)();
};
void winner()
{
   printf("level passed\n");
}
void nowinner(){
   printf("level has not been passed\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   struct data *d;  struct fp *f;
   d = malloc(sizeof(struct data));
   f = malloc(sizeof(struct fp));
   int* new_p = malloc(sizeof(int));
   int* new_p2 = malloc(sizeof(int));
   f->fp = nowinner;
   printf("data is at %p, fp is at %p\n", d, f);
   strcpy(d->name, argv[1]);
   f->fp();
}
```

Why does the address difference between the `f` pointer and the `p` pointer amount to 80 bytes, and the difference between the `f` pointer and the `new_p` pointer is 32 bytes? Similarly, the difference between two `int*` pointers also results in 32 bytes. This suggests that when allocating memory with `malloc`, an actual 80 bytes are being used, which is a significant waste of memory.  Additionally, allocating an `int` with `malloc` also occupies an astonishing 32 bytes. Won't this lead to massive memory fragmentation?

my gcc

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Debugging output:

[image]

I initially discovered this issue when examining the memory address of the `f p` pointer. There was a 16-byte gap between the `f` `p` pointers. I considered the principle of structure memory alignment, but upon further reflection, it seemed impossible because the name array occupies 64 bytes, which should align properly no matter how it's calculated. So, I tried mallocating an `int` and found that mallocing an `int` surprisingly took up 32 bytes, with a gap of 28 bytes between them? Wouldn't this result in a significant amount of memory fragmentation?

Comment: Imagine how fragmented the heap would become if you always allocated very small blocks of memory in the precise amounts that were requested, rather than larger, fewer, more uniform blocks of memory that could be more easily reused.

Comment: Do you know where your fragments will end up? Not really. Do you know how much additional overhead it allocates? Not really. Is it a waste lots of memory? Yes. Won't this lead to massive fragmentation? Yes. Now if you look at how heap allocation is implemented underneath the hood in for example Linux, you'll see that they've managed to make it extremely complex.

Comment: `malloc()` often allocates more memory than you request so that you can resize it with `realloc()` without having to relocate.

Comment: In practice you will hardly ever have a reason to allocate large amounts of single ints, so the allocator is just not optimized for that use case.

Comment: Avoid using dynamic memory allocation when possible for objects with a size of less than 16 bytes. Allocating memory for a single integer is sometimes necessary, but it should be avoided when possible. It doesn't take much for a structure to be bigger than 16 bytes (two pointers will do it on a 64-bit machine).

Answer (score 1):

1. Every chunk allocated has a "hidden" header (preceding the location
   pointed to) that allows the system to return the memory to the
   available space.
2. Additional space may be allocated to reduce fragmentation (lots of
   tiny available blocks, which can hinder the ability to allocate
   large blocks.)
3. Additional space may be reserved to accommodate data alignment as
   required by the machine architecture.